# no expected effect using android:configChanges="orientation"

Tags: android, reload, screen-orientation

I have an issue with my android app when i use `android:configChanges="orientation"`. I want to prevent reloading activity after changing acreen orientation (above xml param works in other app) but this time it fails.

The thing is, that i want my activity (`SherlockActivity`) to keep portrait on start, but after OnClickListener event i need to enable it with:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Is there any other method that should be run to prevent that reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `android:configChanges` parameter should work (it worked for me flawlessly). Just a blind guess - if you're targeting API level 13 or higher, you also have to include `screenSize`:

> Caution: Beginning with Android 3.2 (API level 13), the "screen size"
>   also changes when the device switches between portrait and landscape
>   orientation. Thus, if you want to prevent runtime restarts due to
>   orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher (as
>   declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), you
>   must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation"
>   value. That is, you must decalare
>   android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if your
>   application targets API level 12 or lower, then your activity always
>   handles this configuration change itself (this configuration change
>   does not restart your activity, even when running on an Android 3.2 or
>   higher device).

(excerpt from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html))

Comment: know that, it's just SO's time limitation :) you answered too quickly ;)